# Adding a package to AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS Lambda, I am trying to add a googles `google-api-python-client` to my function and what I've read so far this is the way to do it:

1. I download the file locally `pip install google-api-python-client -t ./google`, then zip the `google` folder, upload it as a layer in AWS lambda `Create layer` section as a .zip file.
2. I do the same with another package `pip install google-auth-oauthlib -t ./google_auth`
3. My lambda function looks like this:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return ('test')
```

When I run it I get:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'apiclient'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

[image]

How can I include these packages to be available in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working with layers, the zip file should have all the modules/libraries inside a "python" folder as here the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path). You can install the package using `$ pip install google-api-python-client -t ./python` followed by `zip -r layer.zip python` and try uploading this as a new Layer and reference that in the function.

You can quickly verify the output of the .zip file using `$ zipinfo layer.zip` or `$ unzip -l layer.zip` to ensure it matches the requirements as per the docs -

```
pillow.zip
│ python/PIL
└ python/Pillow-5.3.0.dist-info
```