# Getting following error: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'google'

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have already tried to create a layer and use that but no luck
[Adding a package to AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61225852/adding-a-package-to-aws-lambda)
somebody, help me how to use google library in lambda function
thanks in advance

Comment: after installing layer for google, Now I am getting following error
Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython' (/opt/python/grpc/_cython/init.py)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.